# Parse- Server Transferring files hosted on Heroku to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, parse-server, pffile

I have parse-server running on Heroku. When I first created this app, I didn't specify a files adapter in index.js, so all uploaded files have been getting stored on Heroku.

So I have now run out of room and I have set up an AWS S3 bucket to store my files on. This is working fine expect for the fact that any files which were originally stored on Heroku can no longer be accessed through the application.

At the moment I am thinking about looping through all objects which have a relation to a file stored on heroku, then uploading that file to S3 bucket. Just hoping that there may be some tool out there or that someone has an easier process for doing this.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are migration guides for migrating parse server itself but I don't see anything in the documentation for migrating hosted files unfortunately.

I did find one migration tool but it appears to still utilize the previous file adapter (on your heroku instance) and then stores anything new on the new adapter (s3 storage).

[parse-server-migrating-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-server-migrating-adapter)